# Creating an index on an SQLite db using DBIx::Class

Tags: database, perl, sqlite, dbix-class

I'm beginning to think that my DBIx::Class tables need indices - I have a few expensive queries over multiple joins and I'd like to see if I can optimise them a bit. Is there a way to create and maintain indices on tables within DBIx::Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Adding_Indexes_And_Functions_To_Your_SQL) says to create an `sqlt_deploy_hook` function and use `add_index` to create the index; for example:

```
package My::Schema::Result::Artist;

 __PACKAGE__->table('artist');
 __PACKAGE__->add_columns(id => { ... }, name => { ... })

 sub sqlt_deploy_hook {
   my ($self, $sqlt_table) = @_;

   $sqlt_table->add_index(name => 'idx_name', fields => ['name']);
 }

 1;
```

Comment: Anybody got any clues as to how to specify ASC or DESC for indexed fields?